# Последний ряд в сетке гридов

Tags: css, css3, flexbox, css-grid

Всем привет. 
Как сделать последние 2 блока по центру? с учетом того,  что количество блоков рандомное,  и если их  3 в строке, то они должны прижиматься к краям.

У карточек фиксированный размер в 285рх

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если у меня 5 карточек, то последние 2 у меня прижаты к левому краю.
Или же, если у меня 4 карточки, то последняя будет так же к краю, а нужна по средине.

Мог бы сделать на флексах justify-content: space-around
Но нужно что бы карточки, когда их 3 в строке, были прижаты к краям.

Никак не могу понять как реализовать. Прошу помощи у Вас.
Спасибо!

тут наброски:

```css
.grid {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 285px 285px 285px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.grid__item {
  width: 285px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;   
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Никак. У вас 3 колонки, значит только 1 блок будет в центре.

Comment: @E_K а если флексами? 
или как то совместить? Или уже проще на js сделать

Comment: `justify-content:space-evenly;` ?